# Get or install HAProxy 1.6 on Amazon Linux (only comes with 1.5 in EPEL)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, haproxy

It's a pain that Amazon Linux doesn't include a package for HAProxy 1.6 yet. What's the best way to install it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm leaving this here for future reference, this worked for me:

```
wget http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/src/haproxy-1.6.5.tar.gz
tar -zxvf haproxy-1.6.5.tar.gz
cd haproxy-1.6.5
sudo yum install gcc pcre-devel openssl-devel
make TARGET=linux2628 USE_PCRE=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1
sudo make install
```

Comment: Some tutorials and blogs will also mention `CPU=native` which enables optimizations for the specific processor on the build machine, but you have -- correctly -- omitted it.  You don't want that option on EC2.  If you ever stop and start the instance, or clone it, or it has a maintenance event and the hardware changes, you will potentially be in for a confusing surprise (such as a segfault on startup) if the instance has a slightly different CPU -- which is entirely possible even within the same instance class. One thing you omitted was Lua, which is new (and potentially very handy) in 1.6.